# Create and execute a workflow of tasks with networkx (Python)

Tags: python, multithreading, graph, task, networkx

## Summary:

The goal is to run a workflow created from a collection of steps (graph nodes) and their dependencies (graph edges).

Is it possible to create a `networkx.DiGraph()` and run a traversal that executes a callback on the different nodes?

### Example:

Please view the example graph:

[image: Possible execution orders of the example workflow]

For that set of tasks and dependencies, the execution possibilities are:

1. step `a` as the entry point
2. step `b` right after step `a`
3. steps `c` and `d` in parallel right after step `b` (step `c` finishes first)
4. step `g` right after step `c` (while step `d` is still in progress)
5. step `e` right after step `d` (since step `c` is already completed)
6. step `f` right after step `e`

or,

1. step `a` as the entry point
2. step `b` right after step `a`
3. steps `c` and `d` in parallel right after step `b` (step `d` finishes first)
4. steps `g` and `e` in parallel (because step `d` finished before step `c`)
5. step `f` right after step `e`

Below, please find the code snippet to create this example graph in `networkx`:

```py
import networkx as nx

W = nx.DiGraph()

nodes = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
edges = [("a", "b"), ("b", "c"), ("c", "g"), ("b","d"), ("c", "e"), ("d", "e"), ("e", "f")]
W.add_nodes_from(nodes)
W.add_edges_from(edges)
```

Are there known solutions to traverse the graph in the manner described earlier, printing the value of the node (step name) and sleeping for a random small number of seconds to simulate a task running and performing some computation? (Using basic multithreading)

Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear what you need. There are a few traversal algorithms in NetworkX like BFS or DFS. You can write a custom traversal function where you can set a delay.

Comment: In short, I'm trying to simulate running a hierarchy of dependent tasks. My idea was to use a graph to represent the workflow, and look to see if it's possible to use networkx to construct the graph and traverse it. I think BFS is closer than DFS to the traversal algorithm that can fulfill this, but I fear it's not quite enough. I'll try to review my formulation of the post with hopes to clear it up more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A topological sorting ([nx.topological_sort](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.topological_sort.html)) would return a valid sequence for the tasks.
Example:

```
>>> list(nx.topological_sort(W))
['a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

In case you want groups of tasks that can be performed simultaneously you can change it a bit to perform a grouping.

```
def topological_sort_grouping(g):
    # copy the graph
    _g = g.copy()
    res = []
    # while _g is not empty
    while _g:
        zero_indegree = [v for v, d in _g.in_degree() if d == 0]
        res.append(zero_indegree)
        _g.remove_nodes_from(zero_indegree)
    return res
```

Example:

```
>>> topological_sort_grouping(W)
[['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'g'], ['f']]
```

Given the groups, you can iterate over them and perform the ones in the same groups simultaneously.